# Имеет ли Input.mouseposition максимальные значения?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеет ли Input.mouseposition максимальные значения координат x и y? Если да то какие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Unity выдает mousePosition даже в случае выхода курсора из окна приложения.

Для ограничений используйте проверки `0 < mouseposition < ScreenWidth` и `0 < mouseposition < ScreenHeight`

Answer (score 1):

`Input.mousePosition` возвращает тип `Vector3`

в котором есть 3 значения: `x`, `y`, `z`.

> Не понимаю почему так но.... используются только 2 значения: `x` и `у` ... Было бы логично сделать Vector2 ... Но, видимо, на такое решение были какие-то причины.

Каждое из этих значений является типом `float`.

Согласно документации `float` может принимать значения в рамках:

> ±1.5 x 10^(−45) to ±3.4 x 10^(38)

При этом т.к. координаты являются целыми числами, то и в значения самого вектора пишутся только целые числа.

Так что какой бы у тебя большой монитор бы ни был в плане разрешения экрана, в границы ты вряд ли сможешь упереться. Мониторов с таким огромным разрешением буквально не существует :)

Минусовые значения могут быть присвоены в случае выхода курсора за рамки области экрана с твоей игрой.

Comment: `Input.mousePosition` часто используется для получения позиция мыши в мировых координатах, где координата z необходима. Чтобы каждый раз не писать `new Vector3(Input.mousePosition, z)`, возвращают `Vector3`.